# Find the last two digits of a sum of eighth powers of $100$ consecutive integers

Tags: number-theory

> Find the last two digits of a sum of eighth powers of $100$ consecutive integers.

**Attempt:**

Since $(100k+x)^8 \equiv x^8 \pmod{100}$, we solely need to find $S=1^8+2^8+\cdots+100^8 \pmod{100}$. By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, if we determine the sum modulo $4$ and modulo $25$, we will know it modulo $100$. Taking it modulo $4$ we have $S \equiv 1+0+1+\cdots+1+0 \equiv 50  \equiv 2 \pmod 4$.

Now, since the number of units modulo $25$ is $\phi(25)$ and $\gcd(8,\phi(25)) = 4$, does that mean we can replace the sum of the $8$-th powers mod $25$ by the sum of the $4$-th powers mod $25$?

Comment: Hint: $a^8=(k-a)^8 mod k$ Now how can this be of use to calculate your congruence?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your last argument, but the problem is not that complicated if you consider the following reductions:

- to compute $1^8+...+100^8$ modulo $25$ it suffices to find $1^8+...+25^8$ modulo $25$ and multiply the result by $4$.
- to compute $1^8+...+25^8$ modulo $25$ it suffices to find $1^8+...+12^8$ modulo $25$ and multiply the result by $2$ and this is not too long

I guess you may find a more elegant solution using rings of the form $(\Bbb{Z}/n\Bbb{Z})$.

Comment: Cant we take mod 10 upto 10 and multiply by 10?

Comment: Yes, that might work also. :)

Comment: So wouldn't the answer be 0 as we are multiplying 10?

Comment: We want to find the last two digits, not only the last one.

Comment: @Beni Bogosel: $1+2^8+3^8+4^8+....+25^8=504 213 653 645=20 168 546 145\cdot 25+20$ and $20\cdot 4=80$. The problem is that $80\ne 30$. Regards.

Comment: Yes, but you combine the remainder modulo 25 to the one modulo 4 to obtain the result: You have the remainder 20 modulo 25, which you multiply by $4$ (since you have four times that sum to reach $100$) and get $80$ which is $5$ modulo $25$. The remainder modulo 4 is equal to 2. Now it is not difficult to see that the only possibility is to have $30$ modulo $100$ to satisfy these two.

Comment: With every courtesy, that's not what you say in your answer. Best regards.

Comment: I don't know what you think it's wrong in the answer, but if you notice, the OP asks about the computation of the sum of $8$-th powers modulo $25$, so that's what I did.

Comment: Asking about the last two digits means modulo $100$. Forget this dear friend. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, but finding the residues modulo 4 AND modulo 25 gives you the residue modulo 100.

Answer (score 0):

If $N=100M+ab$ then $N^8\equiv (ab)^8\pmod{100}$ so the question concerns the integers of the form $10a+b$  where $a$ and $b$ are digits.

Because of $(10a+b)^8\equiv 80ab^7+b^8 \pmod{100}$, we use this table modulo $100$ for calculations
$$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline a & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 0\\\hline a^7 & 1 & 28 & 87 & 84 & 25 & 36&43&52&69&00\\\hline a^8&1&56&61&36&25&16&01&16&21&00\\\hline\end{array}$$
Take the sum of ten consecutive eight powers
$$S_x=(10a+x)^8+(10a+x+1)^8+(10a+x+2)^8+(10a+x+3)^8+(10a+x+4)^8+(10a+x+5)^8+(10a+x+6)^8+(10a+x+7)^8+(10a+x+8)^8+(10a+x+9)^8$$ One has $$S_x\equiv {80a[x^7+(x+1)^7+...+(x+9)^7]+[x^8+(x+1)^8+…+(x+9)^8]}\pmod{100}$$
Calculation gives
$$S_0\equiv {80a(25)+33}\equiv 33\pmod{100}\\S_1 \equiv {80a(25)+33}\equiv 33\pmod{100}\\S_2 \equiv {80a(95)+13}\equiv 13\pmod{100}\\S_3 \equiv {80a(75)+53}\equiv 53\pmod{100}\\S_4 \equiv {80a(5)+13}\equiv 13\pmod{100}\\S_5 \equiv {80a(25)+33}\equiv 33\pmod{100}\\S_6 \equiv {80a(75)+33}\equiv 33\pmod{100}\\S_7 \equiv {80a(95)+13}\equiv 13\pmod{100}\\S_8 \equiv {80a(25)+53}\equiv 53\pmod{100}\\S_9 \equiv {80a(5)+13}\equiv 13\pmod{100}$$
  We see the sum of ten consecutive eight powers beginning by $(10a+x)^8$ is independent of $a$ modulo $100$. It follows
$$\sum_{k=0}^{99}(10a+x+k)^8=\sum_{k=0}^9(10a+x+k)^8+ \sum_{k=10}^{19}(10a+x+k)^8+\sum_{k=20}^{29}(10a+x+k)^8+...+\sum_{k=90}^{99}(10a+x+k)^8\equiv \underbrace{(S_x+S_x+…+S_x)}_{10\text{ times}}\equiv 10S_x\pmod{100}$$
According to the calculation above we have $10S_x\in\{330,130,530\}$
Thus  $$\sum_{k=0}^{99}(10a+x+k)^8\equiv \color{red}{30}\pmod {100}$$